# Undefined variable: artikel (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\uts\resources\views\layouts\home.blade.php)

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, undefined-variable

Undefined variable: artikel (0)

(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\uts\resources\views\layouts\home.blade.php)

```
@if($artikel)
@foreach($artikel as $d)
<h3> {{ $d->judul }}</h3>
<h3> {{ $d->penulis}}</h3>
<h3> {{ $d->artikel}}</h3>
<h3> {{ $d->tanggal}}</h3>
@endforeach
@endif
```

This is my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $artikel = json_decode(Storage::get('public/artikel.json'), true);
  $artikeldata = (object)[
    'judul' => $request->judul,
    'slug' => Str::slug($request->judul),
    'penulis' => $request->penulis,
    'artikel' => $request->artikel,
    'tanggal' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
  ];

  $artikel[] = $artikeldata; 
  $artikel = json_encode($artikel, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  file_put_contents('storage/artikel.json', $artikel);

  return redirect('layouts.home');
}
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `return redirect('layouts.home');` by `return view('layouts.home', ['artikel' => $artikel]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $artikel = json_decode(Storage::get('public/artikel.json'), true);
        $artikeldata = (object)[
            'judul' => $request->judul,
            'slug' => Str::slug($request->judul),
            'penulis' => $request->penulis,
            'artikel' => $request->artikel,
            'tanggal' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ];

        $artikel[] = $artikeldata;
        $artikel = json_encode($artikel, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        file_put_contents('storage/artikel.json', $artikel);

        return view('home',compact('artikel'));
    }
```